# std::filesystem::exists function doesn't work properly on windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, c++17

I write some code as below with c++17 msvc:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std::filesystem;
    std::wstring s = L"c:\\windows\\system32\\applicationframehost.exe";
    path p(s);
    std::cout << absolute(p) << std::endl;
    std::cout << exists(p) << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

and run it on windows 10.
the application prints 0 -> means that file does not exist.
But it really exists and when I try with Cygwin `ls -l` command, it shows a good result: 

`@myuser> ls -l c:\windows\system32\applicationframehost.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 2 cody.nguyen 1049089 69800 Apr 12  2018 'c:\windows\system32\applicationframehost.exe'`

Could you please explain me why and how to solve this issue from code?
thanks,
P/S: the function `exists(p)` works perfectly with almost other files except some in `C:\Windows\System32\`. I just tried to run my application with admin/system/user rights but got same results.
With `ls -l` command I just run it with user privilege only.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] by adding the required `#include`s and `main` function, etc.?

Comment: hi @L.F., I've just updated the code, Please take a look! thanks!

Comment: Try to `#include <string>`.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @vanconNguyen: Is it working for other paths like some file in D drive, etc.? If yes, try to execute this by running VS with admin privileges (Run as administrator). I believe you're running VS17 or latest.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2017, @rubenvb

Comment: `windows` or `Windows`, `system32` or `System32`? On my Windows 10 both start with capital letters. Are you sure that the `filesystem` library implementation is not case sensitive? Docs say: "file name: a string of characters that names a file. Permissible characters, case sensitivity, maximum length, and the disallowed names are implementation-defined.".

Comment: Could you check with the flowing `bool file_exist(const std::wstring& name) noexcept
{
 ::WIN32_FIND_DATAW fdata;
 ::HANDLE handle = ::FindFirstFileW(name.data(), &fdata);
 bool result = handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
 if(result) {
  ::FindClose(handle);
 }
 return result;
}` to check - issue in the MS filesystem library implementation, or somewhere else.

Comment: I'd try using std::string instead of std::wstring, then I'd try using `/` instead of `\\ `

Comment: @VictorGubin: I tried your function with both admin and user privileges, it returned false for both.

Comment: @nada: I tried with `/` as well, and it still doesn't work

Comment: You built a 32-bit executable. "applicationframehost.exe" is not distributed as a 32-bit executable in `"%SystemRoot%\\SysWOW64"`. Build a 64-bit executable, or use the WOW64 virtual directory for the native "System32" directory: `"%SystemRoot%\\SysNative"`.

Comment: Or temporarily disable WOW64 redirection for the calling thread via [`Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-wow64disablewow64fsredirection).

Comment: @ErykSun: thank you so much for your answer. My app works perfect after trying your recommendation!